# Create a windows application using osx

Tags: windows, macos

I have a project to do (an app relied to a DB, used to display and modify data, basically CRUD). The application will run on windows, but I don't have any windows computer (and don't want to buy one) so I will develop on OS X.

So, my question is which language should I use ? I know a bit (but really a bit) in Ruby and Java. I'm a good C# developer, but without windows and VS, it won't be really useful.

My priorities are : a simple GUI toolkit, and a simple packaging/distribution system, because my client isn't good in IT. If I could have fun during development it would be a plus (and I say this because I think Ruby is funnier) but it's not a priority.

So, any programming language/UI toolkit simple to deploy and to use on OS X who could run on Windows ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you know C#...you know all you need: Mono runs on Windows too. Moreover Java is multiplatform too so...

Comment: I like C#, but because of VS and it's ease of use. It's literally the most simple thing ever to create a GUI and app with Visual Studio, but I would try something else, like less windows-centric if possible.

Answer (score 0):

IT kind of depends on your app really. you could make it a web app if you want nice GUI and with easy html css and there is alot precoded for you. hosting on some web service with basic mysql or any other database shouldnt be an issue costs wise and your client can just open the browser and it runs, if he has internet connection available where he needs the app to work. anyway it runs everywhere and since yo know java... thats what i would.

depends on your app really.

Comment: Nice idea ! I didn't think of a web-app. Basically it would be a desktop app, but it's possible to make a web-app. I don't even know all the technical specifications now, but I will keep this in mind. But just assume I will do a desktop app for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Most people that need to do this just get a VM running Windows, and run Visual Studio from there.

Comment: I could, and I think it's what I'll do if I don't have another solution, but I search some good answer.